# Reducing custom font size and image.xcassets in ios

Tags: ios

I have lean plum in my app. it's taking near to 7KB, Images.Xcassets of 6.2 MB, and custom font of 675KB.

- any way is there to use any other SDK instead of lean plum?
- can we save our images in any resource like firebase used for offline savings?
- can we use images inside Images.Xcassets as on demend Resource. so that while downloading app size will be less. in splash screen we can call url to download images.
- any way to reduce custom font size.